# logger is not available in closure

Tags: groovy

some strange behavior : logger is not available in closure
What is going on here ?

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("groovy.my.foo");

def printParameters() {
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("print parameters")

    binding.variables.each { key, value ->
        logger.debug("Name=$key value= $value");
    }
}
```

works only in case logger provided

```
 def printParameters(Logger logger)
```

no problem with parameters ....
  Thanks

Comment: Try inserting an = sign after printParameters. E.g. def printParameters = { [etc ...] }

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? NPE on running printParameters? If yes, @Johnny Wey answered

Comment: Is this in a class or a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable within a Groovy script is [scoped](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22). If you use a type or `def` it is defined as local variable and is not accessible within a method. If you declare a variable without a type or `def` it is added to the script's binding and is usable in other methods.

Here's an example:

```
test = 'output'

printParameters()

def printParameters() {
    binding.variables.each { key, value ->
        println "$test: key=$key, value=$value"
    }
}
```

In your case defining the logger instance as `logger = Logger.getLogger("groovy.my.foo")` should solve your problem.